# Highlighting text on nytimes.com

Tags: windows-8, firefox, touchscreen, highlighting

I read the New York Times on a touchscreen laptop (Firefox, Windows 8).

Whenever I select/highlight text using my mouse, the website seems to think I'm either swiping left or right using the touchscreen, and it sends me to the previous or next article. Needless to say, this is annoying.

Is there a way to disable this behavior? It only happens on nytimes.com, and a few other people seem to have experienced [the same problem](https://www.reddit.com/r/AndroidQuestions/comments/40f6yg/is_nytimescom_disabling_text_selection_on_its/cyub876).